# Youtube automatic upload using node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, video, youtube

Currently I am worinkg on a small application in node js which autogenerate some video content (it hasn't any GUI and it works just in command line). I would like to insert another funcion, I mean the auto uploading and auto publishing videos on Youtube.

I have tried some solutions, for example I followed this tutorial (you can see the source code within the article): 
https://www.codementor.io/johnnyb/uploading-videos-to-youtube-with-nodejs-google-api-du107ynot

It works pretty well, but the problem is that every time the code uploads the video, it is needed to execute the browser authentication on youtube.
Anyone could tell me if is it possible to skip this step and to make all this stuff automatic?

Thanks a lot for any advise. ;)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can skip this step because it is probably created to prevent writing scripts to upload videos to YouTube in bulk with no need for a user intervention.

If skipping that step was possible then people would probably start writing scripts that upload countless numbers of videos to get views and that wouldn't be something that Google would want.

But you may be able to find some more info here in the docs of video uploading in the v3 API:

- https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/insert

They recently disabled the old way of doing that:

- https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_uploading_videos

so some things might have changed recently.